# Using $_GET to recieve the labels off of radio buttons

Tags: php, html, css

I want to print the label off of my radio button to a seperate page, using something similar to this using php

```
<div class="radio"><?php echo "-" .  (!empty($_GET['radio']) ? $_GET['radio'] :'');?>
```

That will be on the other page, but this is the code with the radio buttons on the first page.

```
<div class = "radio" required="required">
<h3 style = "margin-top:-20px;">Meaningless text.</h3>
<label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" id = "x" /> <span>ex.1</span></label><br>
<label for="y"><input type="radio" name="x" id = "x" /> <span>ex.2</span></label><br>
<label for="z"><input type="radio" name="x" id = "x" /> <span>ex.3</span></label>
</div>
```

I have this div in a form, and the form redirects to the page with the $_GET when the submit button is clicked. I want the ex.1, 2 or 3 to be printed when the option for it has been clicked. I have tried, and i am stumped. Help please!

Comment: Try $_GET['x'] but stop reusing names

Comment: Sidenote: ID's must be unique. You're using the same `id = "x"` for your radio buttons. Use "class" if you're using for CSS purposes.

Comment: @EugenRieck Reusing `name` attributes is what radio buttons are for

Comment: @Phil - sorry, bad wording: I ment stop reusing `id` attributes (non-english native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not set the `value` attribute to what you're after...

```
<label for="x">
    <input type="radio" name="x" id="x" value="ex.1">
    <span>ex.1</span>
</label>
<label for="y">
    <input type="radio" name="x" id="y" value="ex.2">
    <span>ex.2</span>
</label>
<label for="z">
    <input type="radio" name="x" id="z" value="ex.3">
    <span>ex.3</span>
</label>
```

I also fixed your duplicate `id` attributes. I assumed from the `<label>` `from` attribute, they were meant to be `x`, `y` and `z`.

The value of `$_GET['x']` (assuming `<form method="GET">`) will be the `value` of the checked radio button.

```
<div class="radio">-<?= !empty($_GET['x']) ? $_GET['x'] : '' ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your HTML as

```
<input type="radio" name="x" value="ex.1" id="1" />
```

This way, your `$_GET` array will have the value ex.1 at index `x`. You can print it using

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['x'])) echo $_GET['x']; ?>
```

Another thing I would like to point out is that you really shouldn't be using same values for `id`. It is supposed to be unique per page, and other elements like CSS and JS depends on you giving unique values for `id`.

Good Luck!